# sugarcrm, nesting level too deep recursive dependency?

Tags: php, recursion, sugarcrm

I create a custom page in views(`custom\modules\Contacts\views`),
Its working fine in local.

I deployed to live hosting server(siteground), here when I try to access that same page I'm getting
`nesting level too deep recursive dependency` **fatal error in utils.php**

Also I'm new to the sugarcrm.

Comment: try this out. http://www.richardlord.net/blog/php-nesting-level-too-deep-recursive-dependency

Comment: Hi vishal, thanks for your immediate reply.  Here in Local machine my php version is 5.2.6, and its works fine here, but is server hosing siteground my php version 5.3.28, so here its say fatal error.

Comment: YES!!So you have to contact with your hosting provider

Comment: no vishal, still same error facing